# Active Record query for update between two ids in YII2 without using row query

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii2

I am noob in the YII2.
I am searching for an update query using Active Record in Yii2.
I need to update some record which are between two ids.

**The Query:**

```
UPDATE
table_name
SET status_name = 1
WHERE
id BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

**What I have tried in Active Record:**

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE table_name SET status_name = 1 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10 ');
$command->execute();
```

But I need Activerecord query **without using row SQL queries**.

Comment: Do you need [updateAll()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#updateAll()-detail)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use static `updateAll` method from Active Record:

```
TableName::updateAll(['status_name' => 1], 'id BETWEEN 1 AND 10');
```

Or query builder:

```
Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->update(
        'table_name',
        ['status_name' => 1],
        'id BETWEEN 1 AND 10'
    )
    ->execute();
```

Comment: let me try this @Bizley

Comment: I have used the `updateAll` 
is there any way to use `BETWEEN` in the application without adding as the plane sql.
@Bizley

Comment: can you help me here, I have to add "Where" condition in query. How does i can add that "Where" in it

Comment: can you help me here, I have to add "Where" condition in query. How does i can add that "Where" in it

Comment: See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder in the Guide (and https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record )

Comment: just mentioning that there wont be any events triggered using any of the above if you are using `EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE` or `EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Like an another solution to question mentioned you can use Update counters:

**Updating Counters**
It is a common task to increment or decrement a column in a database table. We call these columns "counter columns". You can use `updateCounters()` to update one or multiple counter columns. For example,

```
$posts = TableName::find()->where(['between', 'id', "1", "10" ])->all();
$posts->updateCounters(['status_name' => 1]);
```

> **Note**: If you use yii\db\ActiveRecord::save() to update a counter
>   column, you may end up with inaccurate result, because it is likely
>   the same counter is being saved by multiple requests which read and
>   write the same counter value.

**Update:**
Like mentioned in comments for Events like `EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE` to be occur You should do something like this:

```
$model = TableName::findOne()->where(['between', 'id', "1", "10" ])->all();
$model->status_name = new \yii\db\Expression('status_name + 1');
$model->save();
```

This issue was discussed here: [Event EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE does not occur when updateCounters](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/17260)